# jquery - program flow with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I get the expected output, but is it a fluke?

Is `getTemplate()` function which has ajax in it to be *blocking* or not?

```
alert("i want this first");

getTemplateID();

alert("i want this after the getTemplateID() executes");
```

Comment: You need to provide us with much more context than that.

Comment: I already tried, I have two more minutes till i can accept :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a param there :  ( in jQuery ajax).

```
async: true / false
```

if false - so it is blocking.

```
   jQuery.ajax(
 {
    ....
     async: true
 });
```

Comment: You shouldn't really do this. Blocking AJAX requests will block the users browser making him think it may have crashed. Instead do anything you want to after the AJAX call in the "complete" or "success" callback functions (see docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)